# How to colour a variable on basis of highest and lowest or at some cut off value for 3d Bar graph in python

Tags: python, graph, colormap, 3d-mapping

I want to give different gradient colour for z i.e Numeric variable in my 3D Bar Graph on the basis of some cut of value or gradient for lowest to highest value.I want to put condition say if dz is >=50 then green colour bar else red colour ba.  Attached the code, Please share if there's any solution for this.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = "3d")

ax.set_xlabel("Cumulative HH's")
ax.set_ylabel("Index") 
ax.set_zlabel("# Observations")

xpos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]#
ypos = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24]#
zpos = np.zeros(12)

dx = np.ones(12)
dy = np.ones(12)
dz = [100,3,47,35,8,59,24,19,89,60,11,25]
colors=['pink']
ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos,dx,dy,dz,color=colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `color=` parameter to `bar3d` can be a list of colors with one entry per bar. Such a list can be built using a colormap.

Here is an example that colors the bars using a smooth range from green for the highest and red for the lowest. Changing the colormap to `cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlGn', 2)` would color all the bars higher than the mean in green and the rest in red. To set the split condition exactly at 50, you can change the norm to `norm = mcolors.Normalize(0, 100)`.

If only a few different colors are needed, the easiest is to forget about cmap and norm and just use:

```
colors = ['limegreen' if u > 50 else 'crimson' for u in dz]
```

Here is a complete example:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

ax.set_xlabel("Cumulative HH's")
ax.set_ylabel("Index")
ax.set_zlabel("# Observations")

xpos = np.arange(1, 13)
ypos = np.arange(2, 26, 2)
zpos = np.zeros(12)

dx = np.ones(12)
dy = np.ones(12)
dz = [100, 3, 47, 35, 8, 59, 24, 19, 89, 60, 11, 25]
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlGn')
norm = mcolors.Normalize(min(dz), max(dz))
colors = [cmap(norm(u)) for u in dz]
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=colors)

plt.show()
```

At the left an example with a range of colors, at the right an example with only 2 colors:

[image: example plot]

Comment: hi @JohanC Thank you for the solution, it did work but can you please suggest me instead of normalizing the variable if I want to add Condition( eg. wherever observation is greater than 50, I want that in green colour else red colour bar)

Comment: To set the condition exactly at 50, you can use `norm = mcolors.Normalize(0, 100)`

Comment: and if the data range is 111-1112 and I would want to make a cut at 650 then?

Comment: colors = ['limegreen' if u > 650 else 'crimson' for u in dz]